# GameMaker clicks multiple times?

Tags: gml

I'm making a GameMaker game using GML. I have an object "obj_renameServer". On this object, I have the event "Left Mouse Button Pressed". In this event, I've written:

```
serverRename = get_string("Rename your server:", "My Server");
```

However, when I click on the object, it creates ~15 string prompts instead of just 1.

The event is "Left Mouse Button Pressed", not "Left Mouse Button Down"- so I don't know what could be causing this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I never had that problem, but like Bracefor mentioned, you could create a buffer boolean.

Mouse left pressed event:

```
if(buffer) {
    buffer = !buffer;
    serverRename = get_string("Rename your server:", "My Server");
}
```

Mouse left released event:

```
buffer = !buffer;
```

This way the action can't be triggered more than once "per click" (even if that should be the job of the mouse pressed event).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I remember having this issue when I coded in GML... I found a workaround by creating an if statement with a boolean as the condition, and then after the code ran, I set the boolean to false sothat it wouldn't trigger again. It's cheap, but it worked, and I didn't think of it again.

Comment: What was the boolean checking for? Just anything? Or is it checking for a click as well?

Comment: Just create a boolean "clickable" and set it to true by default, and then when you actually click on it, set it to false. Then when the code unintentionally runs again it wont execute that block of code.